# Can't send bitmap over Bonjour

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nskeyedarchiver

I send over an NSMutableArray via Bonjour

```
- (void)sendArtwork {
    NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData *imageData = [self PNGRepresentationOfImage:[bHelp getArtwork:[playerPref selectedRow]]];
    [dataArray addObject:songString];
    [dataArray addObject:artistString];
    [dataArray addObject:imageData];
    NSData *finalData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dataArray];
    [self.server sendData:finalData error:nil];
}

- (NSData *)PNGRepresentationOfImage:(NSImage *)image {
    [image lockFocus];
    NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [image unlockFocus];

    return [bitmapRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];
}
```

And then recieve and unarchive

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

This code works flawlessly in the simulator. But as soon as I run on my device, the unarchiver throws this error.

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x62, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x30, 0x30)'`

I don't get the error on the device if I don't send `imageData` in the mutable array. I'm using Bill Dudney's [iOS examaple](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/resource/NetworkingTesting.zip) and Brad Larson's [Mac example](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/MacNetworkingTesting.zip).

Comment: po the data.  I can assure you it's a garbage value.

Comment: What the data? @CodaFi

Comment: 'po', as in, Print Object.  It's an LLDB/GDB command to get the description of an object.  What NSKeyedUnarchiver is telling you is that your NSData object is garbage.  I'm just trying to get you to verify it.  Set a breakpoint on the line after you've assigned the data you received to an instance of NSData, then po it.

Comment: @CodaFi http://pastebin.com/GkdMN4wy I also notices this only occurs when I'm testing on my iPhone. No problems on the simulator.

Comment: interesting... perhaps one of the classes you're shoving in that array isn't NSCoding compliant

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about Bonjour, you're able to send arbitrary data, but when you read it you don't directly get a NSData object. I would take this question as reference:

[Cocoa Touch Bonjour how to deal with NSNetService addresses and uint8_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721068/cocoa-touch-bonjour-how-to-deal-with-nsnetservice-addresses-and-uint8-t)

So when you read the data you will build a NSData object like this:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes: buffer length: actuallyRead];
//                              ^                ^
//                            Data read       Number of bytes read
```

Comment: The last half of this answer is incorrect. If you archive a mutable array, you get back a mutable array when you unarchive. The original code for unarchiving the mutable array is correct as-is.